# php pg_lo_import is returning empty

Tags: php, postgresql

If anyone can help me, it will be of great help to me!

8 months ago I started studying PHP and at that moment I developed a code together with a professor to save an image and save the OID in the database.

But I changed computers, I'm currently using PHP 8. I'm trying to use the same code, but "pg_lo_import" it's returning empty.

```
pg_query($conexao, "BEGIN;");

$aFile = $_FILES['imagemPerfil'];
$file = $aFile['name'];

$candidato_photo = "img/avatar.png";
$candidato_photo_crop = "img/avatar.png";
$candidato_photo_coordenadas = NULL;

if (!empty($file)) {
    $infoImg = $_POST["infoImg"];
    $oParam = json_decode($infoImg);
    $candidato_photo_coordenadas = json_encode($oParam);

    $dir = 'img/foto_perfil';
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $newName = md5($file . date("YmdHis"));
    $candidato_photo = "{$dir}/{$newName}.{$ext}";    

    if (move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], "../" . $candidato_photo)) {        
        $oid_candidato_photo = "'" . pg_lo_import($conexao, "../" . $candidato_photo) . "'";
        // pg_lo_import IS RETURNING EMPTY BUT $candidato_photo ISN'T EMPTY

        $dst_x = 0;   // X-coordinate of destination point
        $dst_y = 0;   // Y-coordinate of destination point
        $src_x = $oParam->x; // Crop Start X position in original image
        $src_y = $oParam->y; // Crop Srart Y position in original image
        $dst_w = $oParam->width; // Thumb width
        $dst_h = $oParam->height; // Thumb height
        $src_w = $oParam->width; // Crop end X position in original image
        $src_h = $oParam->height; // Crop end Y position in original image

        $dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);

        $candidato_photo_crop = "{$dir}/{$newName}_crop.{$ext}";

        if ($ext == "jpeg" or $ext == "jpg") {
            $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("../" . $candidato_photo);
            imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
            imagejpeg($dst_image, "../" . $candidato_photo_crop);
        } else {
            $src_image = imagecreatefrompng("../" . $candidato_photo);
            imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
            imagepng($dst_image, "../" . $candidato_photo_crop);
        }

        $oid_candidato_photo_crop = "'" . pg_lo_import($conexao, "../" . $candidato_photo_crop) . "'";
    } else {
        die("Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the important parts? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 8.1.0, the `connection` (in your case `$conexao`) parameter in `pg_lo_import()` expects an PgSql\Connection instead of a resource, as it was on previous versions.

Make sure your `$conexao` is from the right type and is initialized somewhat like this - `$conexao = pg_connect("dbname=yourdbname");`

Comment: Hi Gonras! Thanks for your answer! My connection is $conexao = pg_connect("host={$servidor} port={$porta} dbname={$bancoDeDados} user={$usuario} password={$senha}"); Is it correct for this situation?

Comment: Please `var_dump($conexao)` and make sure its not a resource but of a `\PgSql\Connection` type.

Comment: var_dump($conexao) returned "resource(3) of type (pgsql link)". Any recomendation on how to make a \PgSql\Connection type?

Comment: well, it clearly returns a resource.. what does `var_dump(pg_lo_import($conexao, "../" . $candidato_photo))` returns?